# How do I get python to ignore any other input that is not an integer?

Tags: python

**line 8,9** specifically, Just started coding, so I do not know many functions nor syntax in Python. I just want any input provided by the user that isn't an integer (i.e, "I am _ years old") to be ignored. So it could then add one to the inputted integer.

```
print('hello, world')
print('what is your name?') #ask for their name
myName=input() #variable
print('It is good to meet you, '+myName)
print('the length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('what is your age?') #ask for their age
myAge=input()
if not int(myAge) pass
print('you will be ' + str(int(myAge)+1) +' in a year')
```

Comment: syntax error: `if not int(myAge) pass`

Answer (score 0):

Use [try except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) to catch a `ValueError`. It is raised when the input could not be converted to an integer, e.g.

```
print('what is your age?')
try:
    myAge = int(input())
    print('you will be ' + str(int(myAge)+1) +' in a year')
except ValueError:
    pass
```